# Post request using python-maas-client

Tags: python, curl

We can use python-maas-client for accessing the maas API.

I need to know the way of performing the post request towards maas using the python-maas-client.

**Here it is important links:**

*Link for MAAS API documentation:*

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/api.html

*Making GET request sample:*

https://askubuntu.com/questions/581444/how-to-query-maas-api-with-curl

Anyone atleast give me sample post request for MAAS API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sshKeys = {"key": [keyValue]}
maas_access.post(u"account/prefs/sshkeys/", "new", **sshKeys)

The above code will post the ssh key into the maas using maas-api. But in case of user it is not working. Still getting 400 error